# Is there a 'geth attach' man page?

Tags: go-ethereum, mastering-ethereum

Is there somewhere I can find what commands can be used within geth attach, and some examples of scripts as well?

Comment: `attach` opens a communications channel to another `geth` process and all the commands are sent via RPC. Check Ethreum RPC API and this is all you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#list-of-management-apis

Once in the console, you append the command to one of the prefixes `admin`, `debug`, `miner`, `personal`, or `txpool`.

For example `admin.peers`

Comment: Thanks. that's exactly what I was looking for. Ticked as answered, but I don't have enough reputation to give it a vote.